# google-maps web component display blank

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polymer-1.0, google-web-component

I'm using the google-maps web component in Polymer and followed the example:

```
<google-map latitude="7.1907"
                longitude="125.4553"
                api-key="{{apiKey}}"
                on-google-map-ready="mapReady"></google-map>
```

with the style:

```
google-map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

but it displays like this:

[image]

I tried working with the responsiveness and every time the screen changes the maps loads, any ideas or solutions? Thanks

[image]

Comment: any console output? I don´t know about that component, but are sure that this is correct `api-key="{{apiKey}}"` ?

Comment: Yup it is, just copied it from google console.

Comment: Tricky thing there's no console or any errors to work on @elsololobo

Comment: Well I tried the on-google-map-ready event where it logs 'map ready' and it was fired showing the message on the console. But still a grey screen picture.

Comment: try invoking resize on the google-map component.  When the view is hidden and then shown, the map shows blank for me so I explicitly call resize after the animation to get the map to show.

Comment: Tried invoking it the moment map loads up. Changes nothing :( still a grey picture @getbuckts

Comment: I tried working with responsiveness and suddenly it showed up, it only triggered after resizing, any ideas? @elsololobo

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution now. I used the google-map component `resize()` method, according to the [documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/elements/google-map#method-resize):

> Explicitly resizes the map, updating its center. **This is useful if the map does not show after you have unhidden it**.

I never hide the map, but I used iron-pages (so it does hide the map) and the map-ready function was called for the first time but the page where the map is placed is currently hidden at that current point (that's why it won't show anything). So I tried refreshing the map after the iron-page will show the page where the map is located.

[image]